# Disable JRockit Optimzation per class

Tags: optimization, jvm-hotspot, jrockit

Is there anyway to do this?   I have seen there is a -XnoOpt function, but that seems more global than only applying this to a particular class.

Any help would be useful ... even if to tell me this is not possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an opt file, see

JRockit R28: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15059/crash.htm#BABJGICB

Earlier releases: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/crash.html#wp1010461